# Python - From unzipped folder, rename a file and save as csv

Tags: python, csv

Completely new to Python here. I'm trying to automate the process of downloading a zipped file, unzip its contents, select a specific file from the folder, and provide a customized filename and save it as a csv. This is what I have so far.

```
import zipfile 
import csv
import unicodecsv as csv

path = '.../Download'
file_list = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
time_sorted_list = sorted(file_list, key=os.path.getmtime)
file_name = time_sorted_list[-1]
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
for contained_file in myzip.namelist():
    with myzip.open(contained_file, 'r') as f:
        # save data to a CSV file
        contained_file.to_csv('filetocsv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

However, I came across this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-13-189ea422e24c>", line 9, in <module>
    f.to_csv('filetocsv.csv', encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

From perusing over stackoverflow, I understand that the objective doesn't have a `to_csv` function. How can I remedy this issue?

Further, is there a way to customize the renaming function of the saved csv file base on several saved objects in the code? For example, if the downloaded file is crop, water_supply, input_level, and country, then the filename is crop-water_supply-input_level-country.

**Edit**
In response to @Generic Guy's comment, the file I'm trying to save is a .asc file. I can open the .asc file as a .csv just fine. I just want to automate the entire process.

In response to @MedAli's comment, not sure how to best answer your question, but when I unzip the folder, I have the following files:
data.asc, data.prj, legend.png, map.png, select.tsv, and stat.tsv.

All I care about is the data.asc file, which I want to save as a csv file into a separate folder.

**Edit**

When I open the data.asc file using notepad, it looks something like this:

> ncols        96 nrows        78 xllcorner    -80.583333333333
>   yllcorner    20.833333333333 cellsize     0.083333333333 NODATA_value 
>   -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0 -0.00899999961256980896     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0     -9      0      0     -9     -9 1.4900000095367431641     -9     -9     -9
>   -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 -0.00899999961256980896     -9     -9     -9     -9      0     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.4969999790191650391
>   1.491000056266784668 1.4889999628067016602 1.4859999418258666992     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 -0.00899999961256980896     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 -0.00899999961256980896 1.5199999809265136719 1.5099999904632568359 1.5039999485015869141 1.5039999485015869141 1.498000025749206543 1.488000035285949707 1.4869999885559082031     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.5759999752044677734 1.5690000057220458984 1.5620000362396240234     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.5219999551773071289 1.5190000534057617188     -9     -9     -9 1.5169999599456787109 1.5099999904632568359 1.504999995231628418 1.5030000209808349609     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.5349999666213989258 1.5349999666213989258     -9     -9 1.5599999427795410156 1.5599999427795410156 1.5529999732971191406 1.5479999780654907227 1.5420000553131103516 1.5390000343322753906 1.5449999570846557617 1.5319999456405639648 1.5130000114440917969 1.508999943733215332     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.504999995231628418 1.498000025749206543 1.4969999790191650391 1.4939999580383300781 1.4939999580383300781     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.5399999618530273438 1.5399999618530273438 1.5399999618530273438 1.5399999618530273438 1.5369999408721923828 1.5349999666213989258 1.5319999456405639648 1.5260000228881835938 1.5180000066757202148 1.5219999551773071289 1.511999964714050293 1.506999969482421875 1.493000030517578125 1.4850000143051147461 -0.00899999961256980896     -9     -9     -9 1.4520000219345092773 1.4450000524520874023 1.4379999637603759766 1.4329999685287475586 1.4129999876022338867 1.4359999895095825195     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.5429999828338623047 1.5429999828338623047 1.5429999828338623047 1.5360000133514404297 1.5199999809265136719 1.5190000534057617188     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.4750000238418579102 1.4700000286102294922     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.4170000553131103516 1.4140000343322753906 1.4110000133514404297 1.4129999876022338867 1.4110000133514404297 1.4129999876022338867     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.5440000295639038086     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9  1.375  1.375 1.381999969482421875 1.3910000324249267578 1.383999943733215332     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3480000495910644531 1.3489999771118164062 1.3539999723434448242 1.3600000143051147461 1.3619999885559082031     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3220000267028808594     -9     -9 1.3220000267028808594 1.3250000476837158203 1.3300000429153442383 1.3270000219345092773     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3190000057220458984     -9     -9 1.3070000410079956055 1.3140000104904174805 1.3200000524520874023     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3079999685287475586     -9     -9 1.2730000019073486328 1.2829999923706054688     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3090000152587890625     -9 1.2539999485015869141 1.254999995231628418 1.2560000419616699219     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.2220000028610229492 1.2220000028610229492 1.2230000495910644531     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.1890000104904174805 1.2039999961853027344     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.2810000181198120117 1.2810000181198120117     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3090000152587890625     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.2799999713897705078 1.2810000181198120117     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3059999942779541016 1.3070000410079956055     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 -0.00899999961256980896     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3070000410079956055 1.3049999475479125977     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 -0.00899999961256980896     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0      0      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0     -9      0      0      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>   -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9 1.3059999942779541016     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>        -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9
>   -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9      0      0     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9     -9

Comment: What does the file that you are trying to convert look like? If it already in csv form and you just need to change the file extension that should be easy. Otherwise, you may need to read the data in from the file, then write it out as a csv yourself.

Comment: You need to decompress the file myzip.extractall("destination_folder") then iterate through the files within the extracted folder and save them into csv. Can you show a typical zipped folder structure ?

Comment: can you share an example of the data.asc file to see whether it respects the CSV file standard?

Comment: Also share how you want it to look like after conversion to csv?

Comment: The file as you share it isn't conform the csv standard, you need to format it line by line .. and write to the csv file as you want it to look.. so you need to define the output format.

Comment: When I manually open the file using excel, I select the fixed width option (fields are aligned in columns with spaces between each field), it works.

Comment: check the answer below, otherwise share how the file needs to look like after conversion to csv

Comment: your file format isn't csv, it's this one I guess : http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm

Comment: It seems your file should be formatted as a 96cols x 78rows table, but first line (before LF) counts 329 elements. total elements on `split()` gives 2508 elements (including header) instead of 7488 expected. This does not match. Or your copy/paste denaturates the content, or your file is wrong.

Comment: @FabienP, you're right. I got this error `pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 7, saw 96` How would I make the adjustment?

Comment: 96 is ok, then you should skip the header (lines 0 to 6 I guess), try `pd.read_table('your_file', sep="\s+", skiprows=7, header=None)`

Comment: I figured it out. I used `skiprows=6`. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some elements of an answer, based on what you provided so far. If data.asc is conform to the csv standard, you can use pandas to read and write it to a csv file:

```
import zipfile 
import csv
import pandas as pd 
# I assume this code is to get the name of the zipped file
path = '.../Download'
file_list = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
time_sorted_list = sorted(file_list, key=os.path.getmtime)
file_name = time_sorted_list[-1]
# decompress the zipped file here 
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
myzip.extractall("destination_folder")

# you can use the pandas library to load the data into a dataframe 
df = pd.read_table("destination_folder/data.asc", sep="\s+", header=None) 
# and then write it back to a csv 
df.to_csv('filetocsv.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep=',', index=False)
```

Comment: I got this error:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/.../Download\\grid-m1b566d31a87cba1379e113bb93fdb61d5be5b128 (1)'
`

Comment: at which step ? make sure you have the permission to read the file

Comment: I was able to fix the error. Your code works fine. Also, instead of `extractall()`, how can I just extract only the data.asc file?

Comment: @user2105555 you can use extract function which will extract the required file in the currently directory, here the link to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract